# Using undefined in self-executing anonymous function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, global-variables, undefined, strict

I'm trying to implement namespacing using the self-executing anonymous functions in CoffeeScript:

[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)

http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/

I wanted to also protect 'undefined' from being redefined, since that's what the article recommends.

So in CoffeeScript, I can do something like:

```
((skillet, $) ->
  skillet.fry ->
    alert('hi');
)( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery);
```

and get close to the format described in the articles:

```
(function(skillet, $) {
  return skillet.fry(function() {
    return alert('hi');
  });
})(window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery);
```

But when I try to add the undefined in...there's a compilation error due to the strict mode:

http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/07_the_bad_parts.html

"Certain variables such as undefined are no longer writeable"

I was wondering if there's a work around to this?  I would like to keep the strict mode on since there's probably benefits to using it that I am not fully aware of.  But even Googling for ways to turn it off...I came up with nil.

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Generally, I've never had a problem with `undefined` being redefined - any code that does that is simply not good enough to use, and by using strict mode you ensure that your own code is safe from that too. I wouldn't worry about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to also protect 'undefined' from being redefined

and

> There's a compilation error due to the strict mode: "Certain variables such as undefined are no longer writeable"

So what is your problem? There is no need to declare a `undefined` argument, because CoffeeScript won't let you use this "variable" anyway!

If you really (need/want to) worry about some third party script assigning a value to `undefined`, don't use it in your code. You can always use the `typeof` operator or CoffeeScripts existential operator instead.

Just don't worry about it. I think no one ever encountered such an error, apart from explicitly malicious attacks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in wrapping your CoffeeScript code in a self-executing anonymous - that is already done by default by the compiler.

```
alert "Foo"
```

compiles into

```
(function() {
  alert("Foo");
}).call(this);
```

If you want to make sure that e.g. `$` references `jQuery`, simply add a local variable:

```
$ = window.jQuery
skilett = window.skilett ? {}
# ... rest of the code ...
```

There is also no point in trying to protect `undefined` while using strict mode, since (as the error message states) `undefined` is not writable then anyway.

When in "regular" mode, you can generate a variable with the value `undefined` at the top of your code like this (and simply use this instead of "undefined"):

```
undef = ((u) -> u)()
```